# chrome.browsingData.remove or chrome.cookies.remove not deleting all cookies

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v2

In my chrome extension, I want to remove everything. I am using this code

```
chrome.browsingData.remove({
  "since": 0
}, {
  "appcache": true,
  "cache": true,
  "cacheStorage": true,
  "cookies": true,
  "downloads": true,
  "fileSystems": true,
  "formData": true,
  "history": true,
  "indexedDB": true,
  "localStorage": true,
  "passwords": true,
  "serviceWorkers": true,
  "webSQL": true
}, afterCleared);
```

This is removing other things but not all cookies and cache.
I have the following permissions and using `"manifest_version": 2`

```
"permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "tabs" ,
        "<all_urls>",
        "browsingData",
        "cookies"
    ]
```

I tried even using cookies method to delete all cookies

```
 chrome.cookies.getAll({}, function(cookie) {
            for (i = 0; i < cookie.length; i++) {
                chrome.cookies.remove({url: "https://" + cookie[i]["domain"], name: cookie[i]["name"]}) 
});
```

When I use `chrome.cookies.getAll`, after `chrome.browsingData.remove` or `chrome.cookies.remove`, this shows me `0` cookie count. But when I go to history clear option in the browser there I see some count showing in **Cookies and other site data**
[image]

I tried even

```
"originTypes": {
    "protectedWeb": true,
    "unprotectedWeb": true
  }
```

in `chrome.browsingData.remove` but that also is not clearing some cookie. Even not all cache is cleared as you can see in the image. When I clear it from the browser clear option then the cookie count becomes `0` but not from the chrome extension. Am I missing something?